# Output index for reformat component in abinitio

Tags: reformat, ab-initio

I have a acct_id and I need to split them to various output files using Segregate the data based on the acct_id mod 1000 value again

Please anyone suggest me  achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this

In your reformat component, put the below code in the "output-index" section

```
output_index_out :: output_index(in) =

begin

  output_index_out :: if (in.data % 1000 == 0) 0

                 else if (in.data % 1000 == 1) 1

                 else if (in.data % 1000 == 2) 2

                 else 3;
   end;
```

The above sample code supports 4 out-ports, you can expand it to the required number of out-ports